# Bash one-liner to temporarily append path for chained commands without additional bash invocation?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

Consider this:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo "echo YES" >> prog/myprog
$ chmod +x prog/myprog
$ prog/myprog
YES
$ myprog
myprog: command not found
```

I can temporarily modify `PATH` to call `myprog` by name like this:

```
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) myprog
YES
```

... however I cannot chain commands with this approach:

```
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) myprog && myprog
YES
myprog: command not found
```

... apparently the modified `PATH` apparently didn't propagate to the second invocation.

I'm aware I could do this:

```
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) bash -c "myprog && myprog"
YES
YES
```

... but then I have to invoke an extra `bash` process - and even worse, I have to quote.

Is there any way to append to PATH temporarily for chained commands in a one-liner, without having to invoke extra `bash` and quote? Tried backticks, they don't work:

```
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) `myprog && myprog`
myprog: command not found
```

Comment: Just in case, you still can call  myprog by specifying the (relative in your case) path explicitly: `prog/myprog`. That saves you need to worry about PATH modifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a subshell:

```
$ (PATH="$PATH:$(readlink -f prog)"; myprog && myprog)
YES
YES
```

Comment: Oh, that's quite neat, @cuonglm - thanks!

Comment: please note that ( commands ) is conceptually equal to bash -c ' commands '  so you are activating extra bash process. (that I find usually acceptable)

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on what you consider "temporary". For example, you could just run:

```
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog)
```

And then you would be able to run `myprog` to your heart's content for the rest of that shell session. The changes you made to `PATH` would disappear as soon as you logged out. You could just open a new terminal—if working graphically, or switch to a different tty, if not—or run a new session:

```
$ bash
$ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) 
## Do your stuff here

$ exit
```

Another way of running the same thing is:

```
PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) bash
```

That will start a new bash session with the PATH variable changed. As soon as you're done, run `exit` to return to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for that @terdon - by temporary I meant for the duration of the (commands in the) one-liner only

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the path be changed only for the duration of the command.
Then, you need to set it for every time the command is called.
That's a perfect job for an alias:

```
alias myprog='PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) myprog'
```

Use as:

```
$ myprog && myprog
YES
YES
```

Of course, a function with the same name will **not** work:

```
$ myprog(){ PATH="$PATH":$(readlink -f prog) myprog; }  ### DO NOT USE !!
```

---

I am just wondering if you really need any of this. If you create the script inside `~/bin` (after a login with the directory `~/bin` created) the `PATH` variable will already include that path, and the script will be executed by just naming it:

```
$ cd ~/bin                   ### create the dir if it didn't exist.
$ echo "echo YES" >> myprog
$ chmod u+x myprog
$ cd ~
$ myprog                     ### remember to reload ~/.bashrc (re-login).
YES
```